# neutral to ground voltage in ungrounded Y connection

Tags: transformer, three-phase, troubleshooting

A 2 MVA transformer 13.8kV Delta / 400V Y ungrounded neutral the voltage at the LV side of the Main circuit breaker terminals between the neutral and ground is 70 Volts, so, the technician isolated the phases as follows:

When phase A alone was connected the N-G voltage was 138 V

When phase B alone was connected the N-G voltage was 88 V

When phase c alone was connected the N-G voltage was 38 V

When all phases were connected the voltages at the main circuit breaker terminals are as follows:

A-B   390

B-C   388

C-A   391

A-N   240

B-N   238

C-N   240

How to troubleshoot it?

Comment: @user263983 "Just connect neutral to find at source" Do you mean that while the neutral is connected to find what at source?

Comment: Connect neutral to ground at source. Discard previous, typing mistake.

Comment: @OMAR, neutral fluctuations are typical in ungrounded neutral systems. The neutral-to-ground voltage will be defined by the capacitances of transformer LV winding to ground and LV cables to ground, and it is often not symmetrical between phases. You mentioned a troubleshoot, but what would the problem actually be? Is this transformer for PV inverters?

Comment: @Luiz Oliveira No, it's for an industrial plant, the motor loads are critical to be kept operating. one duty and one standby.

Comment: @omar, so, the actual problem was the 70V between neutral and groud?